# How to estimate upper CI of population prevalence of (very) rare events - with weights

Tags: binomial-distribution, survey-weights

I'm doing something equivalent to estimating the prevalence of a rare disease.

I might sample 1000 individuals, and find zero cases. In which case I'd calculate the upper confidence interval using something like `binom.test()` in R. Example, for finding 0 cases in a sample of 1000:

```r
> binom.test(0, 1000)

    Exact binomial test

data:  0 and 1000
number of successes = 0, number of trials = 1000, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.000000000 0.003682084
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                     0
```

So my upper CI is 0.36%.

The samples I actually take are clustered. A cluster might contain 1 or 10 or 100 people - if one of those 100 is positive, all 100 are positive, so I sample only one person from each cluster.

How would I then calculate an upper CI when I find zero in my sample?

Example data:

```r
d <- data.frame(
  w = c(1, 1, 2, 10, 50, 100),
  y = 0
)
```

I have a finite, but very large, sample, and I know characteristics of the sample (total size, number of clusters, size of each cluster).

Comment: Can you not use the 'survey' package in R to do this?

Comment: Using svyciprop() gives me CIs of 0, 0.  Is there another function to use?